# #22 Project Euler - I kept getting wrong answer

Tags: python, project

[The original question](http://projecteuler.net/problem=22):

> Using names.txt (right click and 'Save Link/Target As...'), a 46K text
>   file containing over five-thousand first names, begin by sorting it
>   into alphabetical order. Then working out the alphabetical value for
>   each name, multiply this value by its alphabetical position in the
>   list to obtain a name score.
>
> For example, when the list is sorted into alphabetical order, COLIN,
>   which is worth 3 + 15 + 12 + 9 + 14 = 53, is the 938th name in the
>   list. So, COLIN would obtain a score of 938 × 53 = 49714.
>
> What is the total of all the name scores in the file?

---

```
fr = open('name.txt', 'r')
line = fr.read()
nametolist = line.split(',')

def namescores(nametolist):

    sum=0
    total=0
    for i in range(len(nametolist)):
        nametolist[i] = nametolist[i][1:-1]
    print(nametolist)
    for i in range(len(nametolist)):
        for j in range(len(nametolist[i])):
            if nametolist[i][j] == 'A':
                sum+=1
            elif nametolist[i][j] == 'B':
                sum+=2
            elif nametolist[i][j] == 'C':
                sum+=3
            elif nametolist[i][j] == 'D':
                sum+=4
            elif nametolist[i][j] == 'E':
                sum+=5
            elif nametolist[i][j] == 'F':
                sum+=6
            elif nametolist[i][j] == 'G':
                sum+=7
            elif nametolist[i][j] == 'H':
                sum+=8
            elif nametolist[i][j] == 'I':
                sum+=9
            elif nametolist[i][j] == 'J':
                sum+=10
            elif nametolist[i][j] == 'K':
                sum+=11
            elif nametolist[i][j] == 'L':
                sum+=12
            elif nametolist[i][j] == 'M':
                sum+=13
            elif nametolist[i][j] == 'N':
                sum+=14
            elif nametolist[i][j] == 'O':
                sum+=15
            elif nametolist[i][j] == 'P':
                sum+=16
            elif nametolist[i][j] == 'Q':
                sum+=17
            elif nametolist[i][j] == 'R':
                sum+=18
            elif nametolist[i][j] == 'S':
                sum+=19
            elif nametolist[i][j] == 'T':
                sum+=20
            elif nametolist[i][j] == 'U':
                sum+=21
            elif nametolist[i][j] == 'V':
                sum+=22
            elif nametolist[i][j] == 'W':
                sum+=23
            elif nametolist[i][j] == 'X':
                sum+=24
            elif nametolist[i][j] == 'Y':
                sum+=25
            else:
                sum+=26
        total += sum*(i+1)
        sum=0
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: you can change all of your 26 elseif to `sum += ord(nametolist[i][j]) - ord('A')+ 1 ;` , it would be a start to make this code human readable

Comment: my guess is that your indentation for the if else statements are off since **the code you provided is not valid python syntax** since you have a `elif` after a `for` statement

Comment: shit, mybad, I lost myself in the wrong part of stackoverflow, and people upvoted my comment  -_-

Comment: you can however use `ord(nametolist[i][j]) - ord('A') + 1` to get same result/

Comment: yeah i already edited my comment to that

Answer (score 0):

You haven't sorted the names. In question,

```
begin by sorting it into alphabetical order.
```

So, using `nametolist.sort()` before computing would solve your issue.

But please consider dictionary to do letter-score mapping instead of 26 if cases and also don't shadow built-in method `sum`.
Something like this:

```
import string
#create dictionary
lettersDict = {c: L for L,c in enumerate(string.ascii_uppercase, 1)}

with open('names.txt', 'r') as fr: #using with would be better when opening files
    line = fr.read()
nametolist = line.split(',')

total=0
for i in range(len(nametolist)):
    nametolist[i] = nametolist[i][1:-1]
nametolist.sort() #sort after getting rid of punctuations

for i in range(len(nametolist)):
    wordsum = 0
    for j in range(len(nametolist[i])):
        wordsum += lettersDict[nametolist[i][j]]
    total += wordsum*(i+1)
print total
```